# Suggestion : a site to access all of our sites questions/reputation

Tags: discussion, website, reputation, app-request

Hi, being a quite active Stackoverflow sites galaxy users, I become to be quite tired of always switching from one site to another.

Wouldn't it be cool to have a website that gives me an aggregated view of all my activity on the StackExchange network ? Giving me comments/replies for my questions on all sites where I'm a registered user, even for the area51 created sites (like gaming, on which I registered today), and creating a cumulated reputation graph with tooltips for sites specific reputations.

Comment: This is all available on [your Network Profile page(s)](https://stackexchange.com/users/current) starting in 2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Oh **man!** I *just* started working on this! Stay tuned... it's coming in a day or two. *(Gotta beat code poet!)*</strike>

...and **done!** Here it is:

[OBSOLETE - StackCenter - your one-stop app for everything Stack Exchange](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange)

Here is a screenshot:

[image]
<sub>(source: [quickmediasolutions.com](http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/stackcenter.png))</sub>

Comment: It is kind of useful, but there is no indication of which sites have been recently updated (ie. since your last visit). I think a stream view merging all of the sites would be better

Comment: @Casebash: No, it **does** display an indication of recent comments *since your last visit.*

Comment: Wow, it does. I like it

Answer (score 2):

it is coming soon @ http://stackshot.me - estimated time of arrival is 2 weeks.

Comment: @code wow, i've just tried it..pretty cool app :)

Comment: lolz @system. perhaps I should emphasize the eta (estimated time of arrival) for others who don't have as good a sense of humor as yours.

Comment: @sys: See my app below for a **working** demo.

Comment: Oohh, it is ON! Girl fight! Let's hope one rips the other's shirt off and we see some titties flopping about

Comment: @far - i am reminded of on of my son's favorite sesame street skits with the elmo-tortoise and the elmo-hare 'slow and steady wins the race' as well as the eternal truism 'location is everything'. but really, i wish everyone the best. There is always room for 'competition'.  Wait a minute! who you callin a girl?!

Comment: Well, time shall tell