# OBSOLETE - StackCenter - your one-stop app for everything Stack Exchange

Tags: app, website, obsolete, soapi.js, stack.php

> ### OBSOLETE:  The site and app have been down for years.

<del>**Update:**</del> StackCenter has been completely rewritten to use [Soapi.JS2](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433/soapi-js2-a-fully-relational-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-a). I have also made some changes to the UI.

---

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

### About

StackCenter is a website designed to make keeping track of all your accounts easier. Simply enter your username from one of the sites and you're good to go! You can then view your personal page that lists recent comments to you, overall reputation, etc. all on one page.

As a new feature, I added a **global** reputation graph for the last 30 days so you can see how you're doing.

#### License

*Closed-source*

#### Download

<strike>http://stackcenter.quickmediasolutions.com</strike> (Dead link!)

#### Platform

Any modern web browser with JavaScript enabled.

### Contact

I can be reached at admin@quickmediasolutions.com.

### Code

The application uses [stack.PHP](https://stackapps.com/questions/826/stack-php-clean-easy-to-use-wrapper-for-php) on the server and [Soapi.js2](https://stackapps.com/questions/1433/soapi-js2-a-fully-relational-javascript-client-library-for-the-stack-exchange-a) on the client side. Of course [jQuery](https://jquery.com) and [flot](https://code.google.com/p/flot/) are used as well.

Comment: not sure why this vote is so late, but here it is. The app is shaping up and the code is tiny and clean. good work.

Answer (score 5):

StackCenter gives me my overall rep, as well as rep and comments per site. But it doesn't give me **a dashboard of all my recent question votes, answer votes, and comments.**

I'd like to see my "recent" view more or less with the existing layout -- because it works well, and the "summary" and other detail tabs are useful -- but one view that contains all the sites I participate in.

Imagine this following screenshot, which contains not just SU but all sites as source (and possibly top-15 instead of top-5). Now **that would be really useful.**

[image]

Comment: Well, the API only provides so much information that I can use, but I am trying to get as much as I can on there. I can *probably* get question / answer votes on there. Getting answers to questions will be a little more difficult.

Comment: Expect to see some changes soon!

Comment: I changed the UI and the underlying code. Soon, I plan to add notifications for answers and comments.

Answer (score 1):

I find the idea of StackCenter quite interesting, however I have a few modifications to suggest.

1. I would prefer to have one "tab" for each site.
2. Is content for a site updated automatically ? I don't have a clue about it.
3. In [my question about a site](https://stackapps.com/questions/1111/suggestion-a-site-to-access-all-of-our-sites-questions-reputation) similar to yours, I mentioned an aggregated reputation graph. Are you thinking about developing one? It seems like there are [some charting JavaScript libraries](http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/) available, but is the historical data available from Stack Overflow?

Comment: I'll answer your questions. 1. Sure, great idea! 2. No, I couldn't think of any reason to do that. 3. I certainly could add something like that. Do you have a charting library you recommend?

Comment: @Riduidel: I added 'tabs' now. Actually, a jQuery UI accordion.

Comment: @Riduidel: I have now added a global reputation graph.

Comment: Much more usable :)

Comment: @Farseeker: Any suggestions for improvements / features to add?

Comment: Oh yeah, the graph and accordion are great ! May I ask you one more question ? Could it be possible to display on the graph separate reputations for each site as "stacked sub-graphes", like the one StackTagz uses : http://stacktagz.com/#/stackapps.com/18/george-edison

Comment: Besides, it"s so sad I cannot upvote your question/presentation of Stack Center multiple times.

Comment: What @riduidel said - I'd like to see individual rep graphs for each site as well as the cumulative. What would be nice is perhaps the rep for all three sites overlayed? Might need to use two x-axis though because > 10k vs < 1k will make the < 1k impossible to read. Maybe percentage based? Hmm...

Comment: In fact, the optimal case would have a stack graph (as defined as an example by ManyEyes http://manyeyes.alphaworks.ibm.com/manyeyes/page/Stack_Graph.html) where displayed sites are selected through check boxes. (but I can easily guess it's harder to implement than it is to imagine).

Comment: @Farseeker: Ya, that would be problematic for the reasons you mentioned. I *could* make a graph for each site that represented what percentage of the total rep was from that particular site.

Comment: Seems like the comments shown are only the comments for answers, no ? The comments for questions don't seems to appear.

Comment: @Rid: They should be showing. Are they not showing for you?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is a great dashboard, exactly what I was looking for. I'm thrilled that it includes all the sites that are linked to my Google Account, not just the usual  suspects SU/SO/SF. Yay!

However, some feedback from me, located in Austria (Europe):

On **WinXP+IE7** at work, `Loading recent comments...` and `Loading reputation graph...` is displayed but then neither the comments nor the graph(s?) are displayed, just empty space instead. Might be a firewall or other local issue?

On my **iPhone 3G** (iOS 3.1.3, not iOS4 with HTML5), the comments and graphs also don't show but instead a red text "Error retrieving data." This is on cell data, not on wifi, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Hmmm... the red error text occurs whenever data cannot be fetched from the API sites. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Red text: Interestingly, I only see it on the iPhone, not on my home pc (Win7+FF3, Win7+Chrome). And on the iPhone, I only see it on cell signal; it works when on wifi.

Comment: Aha! Looks like a timeout issue. I hope to fix this.

Comment: Does it work now? I rewrote the app.