# stackauth.com/1.0/users/{id}/associated no longer returning email_hash for some sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackauth, email, associated

I'm not getting `email_hash` for some sites from `stackauth.com/1.0/users/{id}/associated` since sometime after midnight CDT (UTC-0500).

Comment: Thank goodness it's not just me I was just debugging this very thing, which has broken a reassociation feature of my app.

Comment: @Adam: Thank goodness I saw this *and then* saw my app misbehaving and not the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed: http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/febfb878-3f6f-4215-9323-46d15d62ac7d/associated

**Edit:** I discovered this affects [StackCenter](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange) too. Some of my accounts show a funny blue picture because the `email_hash` isn't being passed along.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed.