# stackauth.com/1.0/users/{id}/associated not returning display_name for some sites

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stackauth, associated, display-name

The [problem with email_hash](https://stackapps.com/questions/1238/stackauth-com-1-0-users-id-associated-no-longer-returning-email-hash-for-some-s) seems to be fixed, but now display_name is not getting returned in some cases.

For example: This [Super User /users/{id} query](http://api.superuser.com/1.0/users/12603) returns a display_name, but the corresponding part of the [SAuth /users/{id}/associated query](http://stackauth.com/1.0/users/61ac3c55-d807-4362-b170-f9eda4660552/associated) does not (some of the other sites do have it).

Answer (score 2):

This is because the user hasn't specified a username on those sites yet. The name you see on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/users/12603), for example, is somehow derived from his/her OpenID.

Comment: and @Kevin: I need to fix my code to handle that. The user must have removed his username. It worked yesterday. Why does the Super User /users/{id} query for this user have a display_name field that's not carried into /users/{id}/associated? In other words, why is it in one place but not the other?