# How to monitor answers/comments on all of my multiple Stack Exchange accounts?

Tags: discussion

I am active on 5 Stack Exchange websites, and I would like to be notified when there is a new comment/answer on any of them, rather than discovering it a few days late.

Is there such a tool?
If it could be an RSS feed, that would be perfect.
A webapp would be acceptable too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is now included by default in all of Stack Exchange.

Whenever an answer or comment is posted, I receive a red notification in the "Recent inbox messages" of the top bar.

Answer (score 1):

Well it won't notify you, <del>but [StackCenter](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-for-everything-stackexchange) may be close to what you're looking for.</del> (Dead app and dead site)

It combines the recent information in all of your associated accounts and displays it all in a concise way.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: It is a nice app indeed. But it shows things I have already seen. I would love to be directly presented with the list of notifications of all sites. Basically just a notification that a "You've got a new *" top-banner is waiting for me on this and this website.