# How to get notified when any of the content I have edited or posted is edited, deleted, or closed?

Tags: support, app-request, notifier, editing

How can I "keep an eye" on all my content on SE? Due to [policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172267/notify-instantly-when-a-post-is-deleted), users [aren't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255137/please-notify-users-when-their-comment-is-deleted) notified when their questions or answers are [deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256160/notify-users-when-their-post-is-deleted-or-provide-a-way-to-view-own-deleted-pos), despite numerous feature [requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/send-notification-when-question-is-closed-or-deleted).

I've looked at [StackCenter](https://stackapps.com/questions/1114/stackcenter-your-one-stop-app-for-everything-stack-exchange) but it doesn't seem to do that.

The app would notify me when any of the content I have edited or posted (questions, answers, tag wikis, comments) is edited, deleted, or closed.

Comment: Question's too broad. It's doable, but you'll need a persistent app and a fair amount of not-too-difficult coding.  Start with `/network-activity`, `/inbox`, and `/notifications`. Then cross-check `/users/{ids}/posts` against your app's saved records, etc., etc., etc.

Comment: I've made a userscript to notify you if a question is *closed*: http://stackapps.com/questions/6384/question-close-notifier-a-userscript-to-notify-you-when-one-of-your-questions