# Question Close Notifier - a userscript to notify you when one of your questions close somewhere on the network

Tags: script, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, closing

#### About

This simple userscript checks all of your accounts across the Stack Exchange network, and informs you if a question of yours has closed. Because [SE refuse to do so :(](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/260841)

The way it works is pretty simple; every day, it uses the API to check all of your accounts' closed questions. It then checks whether any of them have been closed *after* you last checked: if they have, a notification is added, if not, nothing happens! It then saves the current time as 'the last checked time' ready for the next day :)

#### Installation

1. You'll need an extension such as [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) (Chrome) or [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) (Firefox). These are userscript managers - installing these will make future userscripts (if you ever install one again) *much easier* to manage and install! They  also provides special `GM_*` features that this userscript relies on to save any data on your computer (such as the last checked time, etc...)
2. You'll need an *access token*. This is simply because this userscript sends quite a few API requests, and we don't want any throttle violations! You can get one [over here](http://shu8.github.io/SE-QuestionCloseNotifier). When you browse on an SE site, it will prompt you to enter your access token.
3. Install the script! <kbd>[Install](https://github.com/shu8/SE-QuestionCloseNotifier/raw/master/questionCloseNotifier.user.js)</kbd> or <kbd>[View source](https://github.com/shu8/SE-QuestionCloseNotifier/blob/master/questionCloseNotifier.user.js)</kbd>

#### How to use

This script does everything for you. When it notices a question has been closed, it will add a message to your SE inbox (client-side, that is!). Everything will work as a normal message does - the red count, the blue notification, and the same style. Clicking it will lead to the question that has been closed. You need to click the 'mark as read' button at the top right of the notification to stop it from showing again.

[image]
[image]

It's only been tested on Chrome. Please post bug reports/feature requests as new answers over here :)

---

If you want this as a separate web-app, see my previous 'endeavour' over [here](http://shu8.github.io/SE-Closed-Questions-Notifier/). I won't be updating that anymore though! So use this instead :)